# style sheets not supported in hotmail and gmail

Tags: css, gmail, hotmail

I've just realised that some emails we send contain the style sheets in the header which I believe is no longer supported by the likes of Hotmail and GMail. Inline style appears to be the only way now

Does anyone know how long this has no longer been supported so I work out what emails haven't been received properly since?

Thanks,

Comment: Cheers, but just looking to know when has inline only styling become the norm for these web apps..can't always have been like that.

Comment: Article from 2007: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-in-html-emails-the-real-story/